# How to get configuration.section on Blazor Server project created with NetCore 6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

On previous Blazor Server projects, that have the Startup.cs I am using this code to retrieve configuration:

```
Startup.cs
{
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration){Configuration = configuration;}
...
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["ApiKey"];
StripeConfiguration.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["ClientId"];
....
}
```

But it does not work on new projects created with NetCore 6, so I copied the code below from this solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIszKSwKu1o) and although it works,there is this warning: ASP0000: Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created....

```
Program.cs
{
....
var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["ApiKey"];
StripeConfiguration.ClientId = configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["ClientId"];
....
}


  [1]: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/156203/using-the-spinner-while-loading-a-form
```

How can the code be corrected to eliminate this additional service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET 6 it happens automagically - `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` initiates DI. So, you can simply do in `Program.cs`

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["ApiKey"];
StripeConfiguration.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["ClientId"];
```

Of course, it *is* possible to tailor the initialization; but the assumption is that in 99 per cent situations it won't be necessary!